# is joining arrays of different sizes possible in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, join

[image]

i have spend hours and days in trying different methods (cellfun, join, horzcat, ... ) but nothings seems to work for what i want

i want to merge/join/relate column3 of dataset1 into column4 (empty new column) of dataset for which the ID of both datasets is the same.

the datasets are not tables, but arrays!

anybody any idea of this is possible to do in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are asking for a simple indexing operation:

```
planes=[7777,5888,6999,5777];
ID2=[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4]; %example data your IDs from dataset 2
ID1=1:10 %example data your IDs from dataset 1
[~,ID]=ismember(ID2,ID1) %Match IDs between both datasets
planes(ID)
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is i have just shown a part of the datasets , such as mentioned the datasets have thousand of rows, so it is practical not really possible to give it in manually all that way

Comment: you don't have to enter it manually. `ID` is the `ID` column of dataset 2. The solution here assumes that `ID` of dataset 1 is unique, sorted, starts with 1, and ends with (number of elements in dataset 1). (I.e. that it is the sequence 1, 2, 3, ...)

Comment: I don't see any manual work involved, From your question I understood that you already have `planes` and `ID` from dataset 2.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez: I have updated the answer, it now uses the IDs from both datasets and matches them.

Comment: @Daniel Just to make sure that this works when `ID2` has entries not in `ID1`, one could do something like `column = cell(numel(ID2), 1); column(ID~=0) = deal(num2cell(planes(ID(ID~=0))));` (`ID` contains zeros in that case)